# shmget system call [Linux] - bytes allocated?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, system-calls

Calling with the following parameters :

shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0600);

I am trying to determine how many bytes will be allocated to the shared memory block ?

I gather it has something to do with PAGE_SIZE (which is 4k [4096] by default on 32bit OS ?).

Comment: I recommend using POSIX shared memory. See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) ....

Answer (score 0):

From `man shmget(2)`:

> `shmget()`  returns  the identifier of the System V shared memory
>   segment
>       associated with the value of the argument key.   A  new  shared  memory
>       segment, with size equal to the value of size rounded up to a multiple
>       of `PAGE_SIZE`, is created if key has the value `IPC_PRIVATE` or key  isn't
>       `IPC_PRIVATE`,  no shared memory segment corresponding to key exists, and
>       `IPC_CREAT` is specified in `shmflg`.

So, in your case, rounding up `sizeof(int)`, which probably equals `4`, would allocate one page size, yes.

Answer (score 0):

From (Linux-specific) `man shmget`:

> A new shared memory segment, with size equal to the value of size rounded up to a multiple of PAGE_SIZE, is created if key has the value `IPC_PRIVATE` or key isn't `IPC_PRIVATE`, no shared memory segment  corresponding to key exists, and `IPC_CREAT` is specified in shmflg.

`PAGE_SIZE` is defined when compiling the kernel and on x86 is usually 4 KiB. Use `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` (or `getpagesize()` when portability is not an issue) to obtain the correct value in bytes when the program runs.

However, even when the allocation would be actually larger, you should not use more than the requested size of the shared memory because POSIX allows implementations to allocate memory of exact size and therefore this behavior can change in a later version.